# Is there a difference between vst1.8 and vst1.32?

Tags: assembly, arm, neon

In the ARM Neon ISA, is there a difference between these two instructions?

```
vst1.32 {d12, d13, d14, d15}, [r4]
```

and

```
vst1.8 {d12, d13, d14, d15}, [r4]
```

Based on the [psuedo-code in the docs](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0406/c/Application-Level-Architecture/Instruction-Details/Alphabetical-list-of-instructions/VST1--multiple-single-elements-):

```
case type of
    when '0111'
        regs = 1;  if align<1> == '1' then UNDEFINED;
    when '1010'
        regs = 2;  if align == '11' then UNDEFINED;
    when '0110'
        regs = 3;  if align<1> == '1' then UNDEFINED;
    when '0010'
        regs = 4;
    otherwise
        SEE "Related encodings";
alignment = if align == '00' then 1 else 4 << UInt(align);
ebytes = 1 << UInt(size);  esize = 8 * ebytes;  elements = 8 DIV ebytes;
d = UInt(D:Vd);  n = UInt(Rn);  m = UInt(Rm);
wback = (m != 15);  register_index = (m != 15 && m != 13);
if n == 15 || d+regs > 32 then UNPREDICTABLE;


if ConditionPassed() then
    EncodingSpecificOperations();  CheckAdvSIMDEnabled();  NullCheckIfThumbEE(n);
    address = R[n];  if (address MOD alignment) != 0 then GenerateAlignmentException();
    if wback then R[n] = R[n] + (if register_index then R[m] else 8*regs);
    for r = 0 to regs-1
        for e = 0 to elements-1
            if ebytes != 8 then 
                MemU[address,ebytes] = Elem[D[d+r],e,esize]; 
            else 
                data =Elem[D[d+r],e,esize]; 
                MemU[address,4] = if BigEndian() then data<63:32> else data<31:0>;
                MemU[address+4,4] = if BigEndian() then data<31:0> else data<63:32>;
            address = address + ebytes;
```

where `size` is a two bit value, it seems like no matter what size is specified, the entire value of the D register (64 bits, 8 bytes) will be copied to memory. It seems like regardless of size specified, vst1.32 and vst1.8, vst1.16 are all equivalent.

If this is the case, the size parameter would be storing at least one extra bit of information (as one is needed to know whether or not ebytes == 8 for the endianness special case). I expect the ARM ISA to not to define storage for extra information so there must be a flaw in my reasoning somewhere or one of my assumptions is wrong.

Comment: Redundant encodings are actually not rare in machine code for various ISAs.  Following the same pattern as other instructions like `vst2.size` makes decoding simpler, so fewer logic gates since it doesn't have to mux between this interpretation and a hypothetical (totally or slightly) different behaviour for the encoding that's actually `vst1.32`.

Comment: @PeterCordes ahh, that seems like a plausible explanation, thanks so much. as for the rest of my reasoning, I still think I'm missing something as if the intended behavior were writing the same values to multiple places in memory, there'd be a more clear way to write the psuedo code (remove the innermost loop and instead use the replicate function outlined here https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0406/c/Appendices/Pseudocode-Definition/Operators-and-built-in-functions/Bitstring-manipulation?lang=en#CIADDJFC) thoughts?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an ARM expert; if I have more time+interest later I'll have a closer look at the pseudo-code, but hopefully someone with more experience looking at ARM NEON documentation pseudocode will see the patterns in it and be able to answer easily.  I'm not sure `vst1.8` is exactly equivalent to `vst1.32`, I'm just saying don't assume there must be a difference.  (They could perhaps be different in big-endian mode, on CPUs that support that, and that might explain some pseudocode complexity.)

Comment: If you are not doing ['lane' stores](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/den0018/a/NEON-Intrinsics-Reference/Load-and-store/VST1-LANE), then I think they are the same.  It does let you keep the 'typing' of the data the same in the assembler.  Ie, you add, mul, etc are type float32x4, then the same data type for the store.

Comment: One of the differences is the alignment check -- if you don't specify alignment, you get "standard alignment", which is to say that if SCTLR.A is 1 then the address must be aligned to the size of the element. So vst1.32 is stricter than vst1.8. There is also an endianness difference -- if CPSR.E is set then the two instructions will store the data to memory differently, because the endianness swap is done per-element. The handling of this is all hidden inside the MemU[] pseudocode.

Answer (score 5):

These two instructions effectively behave the same in the common case (little endian, aligned address), but they differ in two areas:

**Alignment** -- since neither specifies an alignment, you get what the Arm ARM calls the "standard alignment". That means "should be aligned to the element size, but will only fault if SCTLR.A is 1". vst1.32 will fault if SCTLR.A is set and the address is not 4-aligned, but vst1.8 will not.

**Endianness** -- if CPSR.E is set, then each element being stored will be byte-swapped. That means that for vst1.8 no bytes are swapped (it's an array of bytes) but for vst1.32 every 4-byte element has its bytes swapped.

The handling of both these things is hidden away inside [the pseudocode for MemU[]](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0406/c/System-Level-Architecture/Common-Memory-System-Architecture-Features/Pseudocode-details-of-general-memory-system-operations/Unaligned-memory-accesses?lang=en), which is why it's not immediately obvious just looking at the instruction's pseudocode.